# Get system time w/timezone in Django bypassing default timezone

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

As long as I'm using plain ol' Python shell, the `datetime.datetime.now()` command works fine to get system's local (non-UTC) time.

But I'm working on a Django project where the time zone is changed in `settings.py` with `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`.

I've tried many solutions from `django.utils timezone` to `tzlocal` module, but none of them works. All of them return either incorrect or UTC time.

**All of the solutions work if I change the timezone in `settings.py` to my local timezone.** But I can't do that, so is there any way to bypass the default timezone option in `settings.py`? Or any way the `settings.py`'s timezone can be automatically updated? If I remove the `TIME_ZONE` line, I don't know why, but it seems to get a random timezone.

**EDIT -**

I know that the timezone can be entered manually with `pytz`, but I **don't** want to do that. I want to get the local system timezone, but WITHOUT Django's moderation of the timezone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django seems to be putting its timezone in the TZ environment variable. Try `del os.environ['TZ']` then using tzlocal.

Answer (score 0):

To get the time for a different timezone, use this code:

```
# create another timezone instance
import pytz
new_york_tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")

# get the current date and time, with the timezone set in your settings.py
from django.utils import timezone
d = timezone.now()
print(d)

# get the date and time in your other timezone
d2 = new_york_tz.normalize(d)
print(d2)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: I know this can be done, but I don't want to manually enter the timezone. The app should be able to get the default timezone from the computer, somehow bypassing Django's timezone setting.

Comment: "_WITHOUT Django's moderation of the timezone._"

Comment: Does `datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())` work for you?

Comment: No... `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()` just returns `tzlocal()`

Comment: No, as it gets overwritten by Django's intervention.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Javascript to get the Timezone Offset from browser to UTC. Here is the code.

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset()
alert(n)
```

The result is the amount of minutes. For example, you will get 480 in Los Angeles. if the result is negative number, the timezone should be the "West", opposite, the positive number means "East". AND 1 timezone = 60 minutes, so, you can figure out 480 / 60 = 8. Then the result is Los Angeles is in the west 8 timezone. Then you can use pytz to get the local time.

Comment: But that depends on the _client_. As far as I understand the question the OP wants the local time(zone) of the _server_.