# datetime.now() returns utc-5:00 value when running from django application but returns correct system datetime when running from terminal in python

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-models

I need to set a value to the system datetime in my code.
In settings.py in the django application, I have commented TIME_ZONE and USE_TZ= True.

And in my file the code looks like:

```
import datetime

checkedin_dt = datetime.datetime.now()

logger.info(checkedin_dt) # -- gives me a value that is utc-5:00
```

However, when I run the same thing in the python terminal, it gives me the correct systemdatetime.
I want my code to fetch the systemdatetime without setting any specific timezone in settings.py

Any idea why this isn't working in the code. The db is sqlite and the application is a django application.

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099464/python-datetime-now-returns-incorrect-time

Comment: I do not want to set it to a particular timezone. I want it to automatically fetch the systemdatetime. The above link does not resolve the issue

Comment: what is the actual UTC offset of your system? What happens if you pass a tz-aware datetime object, localized to system timezone, i.e. `datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()`?

Comment: For my system, it is UTC+5:00. I want the code to fetch the system datetime directly. I can do this with TIME_ZONE = None but the django webpage expects a definite timezone it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Set `USE_TZ = True` and use `timezone()`:

```
from django.utils import timezone

checkedin_dt = timezone.now()
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: This doesn't work. USE_TZ = True and use timezone() returns UTC time and I don't want that. I tried using TIME_ZONE = None and USE_TZ = False, and it is returning the physical machine datetime. But now, it is unable to load the webpage and throws NoneType has no attribute upper error. I have already spent two days on this problem with no resolution. Nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't include a way to determine the system time zone, but you can use the [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) package for that.

I've never tried it myself, but I think you could get what you want by doing the following in your settings file:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
TIME_ZONE = get_localzone().zone
```

It could still fail if the name of the timezone can't be determined, since `TIME_ZONE` must be a string name.

Comment: This returns the TIME_ZONE as 'America/Chicago'. However, it should return 'Asia/Kolkata'. Why does it fail to return the correct localzone? I am observing this for almost most methods unless TIME_ZONE is explicitly defined

Comment: @devcoder.027: What happens if you run `get_localzone()` in a Python shell, outside of Django? Are you setting the Django timezone as above or are you checking the value later on in the Django process? If the latter, it may be because Django is setting the time zone environment variable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41604291/2395796).